# Difference between Object and instance : C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, instance

I followed a number of posts on SO, and finally I can draw a conclusion that when we 
have something like :

```
Person name;
```

`name` is an object of class `person`.

It becomes instance when instantiate  it :

```
name=new Person();
```

I am a beginner in C++, and so far I have seen we can access the functions and variables like:

```
Person name;
name.getValue;
name.callFunction();
```

We need not to use `new` operator for this. So can we say the differentiating factor between an object and instance can be ignored in C++?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157122/object-creation-on-the-stack-heap about creating objects on the stack or heap.

Comment: In C++, an object is a region of storage.

Comment: The terms object and instance are exchangeable. `new` creates a heap allocated object without automatic storage duration. The return type of `operator new()` is a pointer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++ "object" and "instance" are used nearly interchangably.

There is a general programming design pattern of `class` and `instance`.  The `class` holds the (common) information about all `instance`s in that `class`.  (Not ALL information about ALL instances - rather, the SUBSET of information that ALL instances have in common)

In C++ when you declare a `class` or `struct`, the compiler makes code that describes how you create an `instance` of that `class`, what the data layout is, and provides some methods that can be used to interact with that `instance` (up to and including destruction).

`virtual` methods and inheritance seemingly moves some of the methods and layout to the instance: but the amount is quite limited.  Instead, each instance holds pointers to `virtual` class data.  In some languages, you can do things like replace individual methods of an instance at runtime: but not in C++.

When you create an instance of that `class` or `struct`, it can be via an automatic named variable on the stack (like `Foo f;`), an anonymous automatic named variable (like `some_function( Foo(17,22) )`), an instance on the free store (like `new Foo(17, 22)`), or via placement-`new` (which is how `std::vector` and `std::make_shared` creates instances).

Confusingly, there is a separate parallel `class`-`instance` pattern in C++ -- `class template`-`class`.  The `class template` is the `class`, the instantiation is the instance.  The `template` arguments and specializations indicate how, at compile time, you can "construct" the `class`es.  Pattern matching on the `class template`s provide a limited amount of properties that are not tied to the instances ("class properties" in the pattern).  (Arguably the function template-function is another ... instance ... of the class-instance pattern).

If you look at the [C++1y proposal for concepts lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) you will see where object and instance might mean different things in C++.

```
int x = 0;
int& foo = x;
int* bar = &x;
```

`x` is both an object and an instance of the type `int`.

`foo` is an instance of the type `int&`, but calling `foo` an object is probably wrong!  It is a reference -- an alias, or a different name for some object (in this case `x`).

`bar` is a pointer to an `int`, which is an instance of type `int*`, and calling it an object is probably correct.

This is a useful distinction: a type does not have to denote an object type if it is a reference type.  Object types behave differently than reference types in a number of important ways.

Now, some types have "reference semantics", in that they behave like references in many ways, but are actually `class`es.  Are instances of such a type better called references or objects?  In horrible cases, some instances have a mixture of both reference and object semantics: such is often a bad sign.

Via [latest standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) in 3.9 [Types] we have the kinds of types in C++.  They describe what an *object type* is:

> Types describe objects (1.8), references (8.3.2), or functions (8.3.5)

and

> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.

So calling the "instances" of things that are function types or reference types "objects" seems incorrect.  Note that accessing the "representation" of a function or a reference instance is basically impossible: references alias into the object they refer to, and using the name of a function decays to a pointers-to-functions at the drop of a hat (and pointers-to-a-function are basically opaque handles that let you invoke them).

So arguably functions are not instances, and references are not instances.

On the third hand, we do talk about instantiations of `class` `template`s and function `template`s.  14.7 is "template instantiation and specialization", and points of instantiation (of a `template`) are all formal terms from the standard.

Comment: I've searched in the C++11 draft. The word "instance" only appears a few times (mostly in "for instance" :)). I think your point is interesting, and I would probably use the same terminology, but can you point to a place in the standard where it actually talks about an "instance of reference type"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Nope, the standard doesn't seem to talk about instances of non-object types generically.  It refers to objects and references, but I cannot find a generic term for "instance of a type" used in the standard...

Answer (score 8):

First, you should know that there is no difference between "object" and "instance". They are synonyms. In C++, you also call instances of primitive types like `int` or `double` "objects". One of the design principles of C++ is that custom types (i.e. classes) can be made to behave exactly like primitive types. In fact, in C++, one often prefers to refer to "types" and not "classes".

So, *types* and *objects* it shall be. Now that we've settled this, I'm afraid I must tell you that your conclusions are wrong.

`Person` is a *type*.
`name` is a (not very well named) variable to access an *object* of that type.

A whole line of C++ code would look like this:

```
Person name;
```

This means: "create an object of type Person and let me access it via the name variable".

`new Person()` is much more complicated. You may be familiar with the `new` keyword from languages like Java, but in C++, it's a very different beast. It means that a new object of type `Person` is created, but it also means that **you are responsible for destroying it** later on. It also gives you a different kind of handle to the newly created object: a so-called *pointer*. A `Person` pointer looks like this:

```
Person*
```

A pointer is itself a type, and the types `Person*` and `Person` are not compatible. (I told you that this would be much more complicated :))

You will notice the incompatibility when you try to compile the following line:

```
Person name = new Person();
```

It won't compile; you will instead receive an error message. You'd have to do it like this instead:

```
Person* name_ptr = new Person();
```

And then you'd have to access all the members of `Person` with a different syntax:

```
name_ptr->getValue();
name_ptr->callFunction();
```

Finally, remember you must explicitly destroy the object in this case:

```
delete name_ptr;
```

If you forget this, bad things can happen. More precisely, your program will likely use more and more memory the longer it runs.

I think that pointers are too advanced yet for your level of C++ understanding. Stay away from them until you actually need them.

Comment: So there is absolutely  no difference between object and instance?

Comment: Right, there is absolutely no difference. Have a look at this FAQ from isocpp.org: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#overview-object

Answer (score 5):

Object and instance are two words for the same thing.

Comment: Furthermore, you should always say *instance of*. So a certain object is an instance of a certain class.

Comment: @DSquare: that's debatable. You will find that many C++ programmers talk about "objects". IIRC this is also the preferred terminology in the standard (someone correct me if I'm mistaken).

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm not saying that you should always say "instance", I'm saying that If you say "instance" what you are saying is a short-hand for "instance of [class]". And we know that an instance of a class is an object. So "instance" equals "object".

Answer (score 2):

"Object" and "instance" are almost interchangeable. In C++, an object is formally any region of storage. "Instance" is not a formally defined term, but we typically refer to "instances of type `X`", most commonly used with class types.

```
Foo f;
```

This declaration creates an object named `f`. The object's type is `Foo`. You could say the object `f` is an instance of `Foo`.

Your attempt to distinguish the terms was incorrect. The two things you've actually pointed out are two different ways of creating objects.

```
Person name;
```

In this case, we're creating an object `name` of type `Person`.

```
Person* name = new Person();
```

In this case, we're creating an object `name` of type `Person*` (pointer to `Person`). We are also creating another object of type `Person` using the expression `new Person()`. This expression returns a pointer, which we are initialising the `name` object with.

Comment: What i have distinguished, will that be correct if we refer Java instead  of C++?

Comment: @joeyrohan No, but "instance" is much more of a Java term. In Java, people tend to talk about "instances of `X`" rather than "objects of type `X`".

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple but very important

Take a general example:  what is the general meaning of object? its nothing but which occupies some space right....keep that in mind we now talk about Object in java or C++

example: here I am creating Object      **Student std=new Student();**

where **Student** is a **Class** and **std** is a **Object** because we Created a memory for std with the help of **new** keyWord it means it internally occupies some space in memory right thats y we call **std** as **Object**

if you won`t create memory for an object so we call that **object** as **instance**.

example: Student std;

here **Student** is a class and **std** is a instance(means a just a copy that class),with this we won`t do anything untill unless we create a memory for that.

Thats all about object and Instance :)