# what actually it means when we say "initialize the object" in c++?

Tags: c++, object

I have tried to research it.. but I think everything is an object in c++....
like (int, float) are scalar objects..etc.

But when we create class's instance, documentation refers the "initialize an object with constructor" in c++. What does it actually means.

Comment: very related/may dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c.  I'm looking for more

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat

Comment: The wikipedia article on initialization is probably worth a read: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)

Comment: initialize = set the initial value; object = memory containing an instance of a class

Comment: int and float are built-in types. struct A {}; A is also a type, a user-defined type. It is not an object. An object is an instance of a class. A a; a is the object, A is the type. When you initialize an object, it means you instanciate it (by means of a class constructor). An object is initialized when you give it an initial value. Example: std::vector<int> {1,2,3};

Comment: @MFnx you mean int and float are not objects?

Comment: @sparshgoyal int and float are types, and in particular, built-in types. An object is an instance of a class. int and float are not really classes. Let's assume int and float are classes, then in the declaration int i; or float f; i and f are objects, int and float are types.

Comment: see this,     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821936/what-is-a-scalar-object-in-c

Comment: To which "documentation" are you referring exactly?

Comment: @MFnx The way the C++ Standard uses "object", variables of scalar types like `int` or `float` are also considered objects, not just class types. Their initializations do not use constructors.

Answer (score 4):

> I think everything is an object in c++

By the letter of the standard, an "object" is "a region of storage". You can read the nitty-gritty details under [`[intro.object]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object).

But in layman's terms yes you are right.

> like (int, float) are scalar objects..etc.

Absolutely. An `int` is an object. A `float` is an object.

(Of course, `int` and `float` themselves are *types*.)

> But when we create class's instance, documentation refers the "initialize an object with constructor" in c++.

There's nothing wrong with that. You can initialise an `int`, and you can initialise a `float`, and you can initialise an object of class type. For the latter case, one way to do that is using a constructor. That doesn't change anything.

> What does it actually means.

Exactly what it says: performing the steps needed to give some object an initial value.

I'll caution you also that there is a lot of bad "documentation" (notably poor tutorials etc.) for C++ out there on the web, so it's also possible that you came across badly-worded or flat-out incorrect text. Notice that, even in the comments section under your question, some people got this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> everything is an object in c++.... like (int, float) are scalar
>   objects

This is wrong. `int` and `float` are built-in types. The user can define it's own types, like for example:

```
struct A {};
```

Here, `A` is a user-defined type. It is not an object!

An object is an instance of a type:

```
A a;
int i;
```

Here, `a` and `i` are objects of type `A` and `int`. When you initialize an object of type `A`, it means you instanciate class `A` and initialize it by calling one of the class constructors.

Another example:

```
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3}
```

Here, the object `v` of type `std::vector<int>` is initialized with the values `{1,2,3}`, by calling the constructor of the class `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Any reference for that statement? According to this, I think I'm correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206044/difference-between-object-and-instance-c

Comment: @Caleth Yes exactly. x is an object and an instance. I think that is what I'm saying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think MFnx is saying that `int` is a *type*. Instances of `int` are objects

Comment: Okay, this wording is much more clear. Before, it read like you were saying that _a_ `int` is not an object. On the other hand, I think it's clear that the OP meant instances-of, not the types themselves.

Comment: Exactly. How int can be an object? "An int", being, a object of type int, is an obj. But "int" is not an object as far as I know. I got downvoted hardly there lol due to "an int" vs "int" lol.

Comment: I think you're just reading the question too pedantically :P The original version of your answer pretty heavily read as if a thing had to be of class type to be deemed an object. It's better now. +1

Comment: Still, I've changed "An object is an instance of a class" to "An object is an instance of a type", to avoid confusion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Pedantically maybe :) But if you talk with someone who says object, when he refers to a class, that's really confusing (happened to me more than once).

Comment: @aschepler Are you sure? Instantiating a type sounds weird, or is it correct?

Comment: Well "instantiate" means something else in C++, related to templates. "Instance" isn't a formal technical term, but I think it sounds fine to say `i` is an instance of the type `int`. More technically, we would say `i` is a variable of type `int`, which names an object of type `int`.

Comment: `foo a;` is read as "a is an instance of object foo", foo is also user data type. So int is also an object.

Comment: @seccpur I do not agree.

Answer (score -2):

Creating an object in C++ has 2 steps:

1) find some memory to contain the object.

This can be some space in the stack frame of the function for local objects or the data section for global objects. In those cases the compiler deals with that. Or `operator new` is used to dynamically create an object and allocates some memory. Which is the case if you write "new Foo()" anywhere.

2) "initialize an object with constructor"

This simply means the constructor is called. The address from step 1 is passed as `this` to the constructor and any arguments you specified too. If you have no constructor then the default constructor is used when possible.

Comment: You've got a few assumptions about "location" going on here.

Comment: _"This simply means the constructor is called"_ No, it means much more than that.

Comment: The whole premise of the question is initialising `int`s and `float`s and how that works with the definition of "object"

Comment: Not how I read it. He said `class instance` for the second stanza. I don't consider ints classes. But if you want to extend this then one way to look at is that int, float, ... do have an empty constructor that simply does nothing.

Comment: Yes, and the whole point of the second paragraph is that it contrasts with the first in which he names `int`s and `float`s specifically. And, no, `int`s and `float`s do not have "an empty constructor".