# Declare and initialize pointer to a class instance in one line

Tags: c++

Assuming I have a class `MyClass(int i)`, I know I can do:

```
int j = 1;
MyClass instance(j);
```

i.e. declare and initialize `instance` in one line. Is there a *short* syntax that allows to do the same for a pointer to `MyClass`?

```
MyClass *instance = new MyClass(j);
```

works, but the syntax has "MyClass" two times, which is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> MyClass *instance = new MyClass(j);
> ```
>
> works, but the syntax has "MyClass" two times, which is a bit
>   redundant.

How about:

```
 auto instance = new MyClass(j);
```

But why will you want to allocate on the heap? See [Object creation on the stack/heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157122/object-creation-on-the-stack-heap)
and [Proper stack and heap usage in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c)

Comment: Oh, busted, didn't think of `auto`. Well it doesn't include `MyClass` twice but I think OP was looking something shorted. Anyway, you deserve an upvote.

Comment: @gsamaras, :-) .. `auto` [AAA](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Answer (score 0):

***No.***

You should do it as you say.