# C++: what if we don't allocate an object with new, but the class itself contains a new in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

Hope my question isn't confusing. I'll explain that with code.
I'm learning constructor/desctructor and new/delete in C++. While comparing two piece of code, I'm thinking about where the object and it's members are allocated.

I got a little bit confused when I see the new in constructor and main, and delete in destructor and main:

In the first example, I think local object c is allocated in stack. And that means, members list pointer, two int values (size and capacity) are all in stack. The object also contains an array in size 10, however the array itself is allocated in heap since new is used. When the program ends, the local object c (including the pointer) will be freed automatically. And the array pointed by pointer list will be freed as well, by destructor. Is that correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Collector {
  int * list;
  int size;
  int capacity;

  public:
  // Default constructor
  Collector(){
    // We must define the default values for the data members
    list = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    capacity = 0;
  }
  
  // Parameterized constructor
  Collector(int cap){
    // The arguments are used as values
    capacity = cap;
    size = 0;
    list = new int[capacity];
  }

  bool append(int v){
    if (size < capacity) {
      list [ size++ ] = v;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // A simple print function
  void dump(){ 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
      cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  
  ~Collector(){
    cout << "Deleting the object " << endl;
    if (size > 0)
      delete[] list; 
  }
};

int main(){  
  Collector c(10); 
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
    cout << c.append(i) << endl;
  }
}
```

Now compared with the second example, object is created with new. So all members including pointer and two int values are all allocated from heap. The array itself is also in heap for the same reason as the first example. Before the program ends, there is a delete so the pointer and two int values are all freed. The array is also freed since the desctructor is called when delete command is issued. Is my understanding correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Collector {
  int * list;
  int size;
  int capacity;

  public:
  // Default constructor
  Collector(){
    // We must define the default values for the data members
    list = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    capacity = 0;
  }
  
  // Parameterized constructor
  Collector(int cap){
    // The arguments are used as values
    capacity = cap;
    size = 0;
    list = new int[capacity];
  }

  bool append(int v){
    if (size < capacity) {
      list [ size++ ] = v;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // A simple print function
  void dump(){ 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
      cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  
  ~Collector(){
    cout << "Deleting the object " << endl;
    if (size > 0)
      delete[] list; 
  }
};

int main(){  
  Collector *c;
  c = new Collector(10); 
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
    cout << c->append(i) << endl;
  }
  delete c;
  cout << "Exiting program" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Seems a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157122/object-creation-on-the-stack-heap.