# Pointers and References locations

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

When I tried to find where **Pointers** store themselves, their addresses, and address values. The same with **References**.

**Example 1:**

```
int a = 1;
int *b = new int{ 5 };
int &c = a;
```

I know that `a` with `1` are stored on the stack, but are they in the same memory block?

I have information, that `*b` with a reference to value `5` are stored on the stack, but the value `5` is stored in the heap.

I heard that `&c` with a reference to a isn't stored in the memory because it's an alias. But other people said another thing, so the same question as for `*b`, how are they all stored in memory?

*I think it would be much more interesting to know deeper about this topic.*

**Example 2:**

```
void Func1(int a)
{
// code
}

void Func2(int *b)
{
// code
}

void Func3(int &c)
{
// code
}
```

I know that argument `a` is copied to the function memory on the stack.

I have information that `*b` is copied to the function memory on the stack, but copied only `*b`, not its reference to the value which is stored in the heap.

I heard that `&c` don't copy because the function uses the value located on the heap directly through this reference.

---

How do examples **1** and **2** actually work in memory?

I tried to find answers to this question using Google, Bing AI and ChatGPT, but answers vary.

My compiler is x64 MSVC 14.35.32215

Comment: `a` *might* be on the stack. There's not enough context to say. Also note that the C++ specification doesn't actually specify exactly where variables are stored, it's just that it's easy for compiler to store local variables on the stack.

Comment: Regarding `b`, it's the variable `b` itself that might be stored on the stack. It's value is then the memory address that was allocated by `new`. So `b` is the variable on the stack, `*b` is the value `5` stored on the heap.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157210/1968

Comment: Of course answers with Bing AI and ChatGPT vary - they just make stuff up. There is no reason to expect any of them to be correct about anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the types `int` and `int*` are stored on the stack. A reference is an alias, and as such, may not require any additional storage, depending on compiler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First, address of a variable is just an integer.
Now, look into your first example:

```
int a = 1;
int *b = new int{ 5 };
int &c = a;
```

`a` is on stack, it takes 4 bytes. The bytes represent value `1` in binary format, this [reference](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/data-analysis/itdtHTML/node55.html) visualizes how is an integer stored in memory.

About `b`, you're right. `b` is a pointer, it has its own address on stack and takes 4 bytes (or 8 bytes depending on OS, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/raw-pointers?view=msvc-170). The 4 bytes represent an integer value, which is address of `5` lying on heap (`new int{ 5 }`).

About `c`, it's exactly an alias of a, C++ might need memory to help other parts of your program aware of the existence of the alias.

From here, hope you can self-answer your questions.

Comment: While a reference is an alias, it is tied to a specific address of what's aliased. Very similar to the way a const ptr is tied to a specific address. For example, `int& ri = v[0];;` where v is a vector of ints is not an alias of v[0] if one pushes an int onto v because the location of `v[0]` may well be changed. Be very careful when thinking of a reference as an alias. There be dragons.