Stack dynamic or heap dynamic variable
In the function
int main() {
    int *p=new int;
    return 0;
}

is p an explicit heap dynamic variable or stack dynamic variable?
I am aware that p is a variable pointing to a value in the heap, but I am confused as to if p is an explicit heap dynamic variable or stack dynamic variable as well.

That is not C code. C++ has new. C does not. Both languages use storage duration as a concept for object lifetimes, and neither specifies implementations details regarding heaps or stacks.

Why would the type of p depend on what it points to? You can reassign p to point to a local variable or global variable.

“[explicit] heap dynamic variable” and “stack dynamic variable” are not established terms in the context of C++. It is therefore not clear what you mean. Furthermore, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157210/1968

A pointer is a separate thing from the thing it points to.
int *p in block scope defines an object named p with automatic storage duration. Objects with automatic storage duration are most commonly implemented with a stack except as altered by optimization, which may keep the object’s value in a register or, in some situations, eliminate it entirely.
The fact p is initialized to point to dynamically allocated memory is irrelevant to the storage duration of p. A pointer with any type of storage duration may point to an object with any type of storage duration.
