# Memory locations of classes (refers to Inside the C++ object model book)

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am currently reading Inside the C++ Object Model. On page 9 it has a diagram showing how the contents of a class are laid out in memory. It states the only part of an object which actually resides in the class memory are non-static data members.

Here is a post from SO regarding the contents of memory for a program:

[Global memory management in C++ in stack or heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap)

In the second answer it details the memory layout of a program- showing the stack and the heap.

Does the location of the static data members/any class function (basically the parts of the class which are not stored within the object- referring to page 9) change depending whether the object is on the stack or the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static data members reside in the same area of memory that global variables and plain static variables would reside. It is the "class memory" that could either be on the stack or heap, depending on how the instance of the class was created.

A static data member is not too different from a global variable. However, it is scoped by the class name, and its access by name can be controlled via `public`, `private`, and `protected`.  `public` gives access to everyone. `private` would restrict access to only members of the class, and `protected` is like `private` but extends access to a class that inherits from the class with the static data member.

In contrast, a global variable is accessible by name by everyone. A plain static variable is accessible by name by code in the same source file.

A plain class method is actually just a regular function (modulo access controls), but it has an implicit `this` parameter. They do not occupy any space in a class. However, a `virtual` class method would occupy some memory in the class, since it has to resolve to a derived class's implementation of the method. But, polymorphism is likely not yet covered where you are in  your textbook.

Comment: Just to confirm, page 9 of said book states that a non-static function is also stored separately from the class object? I can understand why static stuff is (as you only have one copy of them, hence static) but I was surprised to read non-static functions weren't included in the object.

Comment: @user997112: Class methods are like static methods, except the `this` parameter is implicit, while static methods have no `this` parameter (since the method is supposed to apply to any instance).

Comment: Thanks- I think I just answered my own question in my comment to the other poster. Its only the non-static data members which must be specific per object because they form the "state" of the object and can vary per object. In contrast, a class function is the same for whatever instance of that class?

Comment: @user997112: Yes, except for `virtual`, as I stated in my edit. Regards

Answer (score 2):

No, where variables are allocated doesn't affect the storage of static data or code. These are generally stored in separate memory areas, that are neither stack or heap.

Functions and static data members are special in that that there is only one copy of each in the whole program.

Variables of class, or other, types are most often created and destroyed multiple times during  a program run.

Comment: So basically, because non-static data members contribute to the "state" of an individual object- they are the only things to be included within the object address space? They have to be unique because each object could have different data member values. In contrast a non-static function is still the same function no matter which non-static object accesses it?

Comment: Yes, the non-static data is specific to each object, so there could be many copies. The static data is shared, so there is only one copy of that. A member function only differs from an "ordinary" function in that it has a `this` pointer showing which object it was called for. Static member functions don't have `this`, so they are *very* similar to free functions (except they can be private, to limit access).