# Memory issue with c program

Tags: c, memory-management

So,i was solving a problem on **SPOJ**.I have to handle large number of values of order **2^18**.I am on a system with **4 GB** ( 2**34 Bytes) ram. While allocating memory for my program , i observed something strange. I am using **long long** qualifier for storing the input in two arrays `sum1[1<<17]` and `sum2[1<<17]`.So, total memory allocated by the two arrays is `2^17*8 + 2^17*8 = 2^21 Bytes`.The part of code i want to refer is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // some code 
    int a=17,b=17;
    long long sum1[1<<a], sum2[1<<b]; 

    // some more code 
}
```

The problem is that whenever `a+b >= 34` , the program stops working, else it works fine.I guess it is due to unavailability of large space. But if i make the two arrays global like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long sum1[1<<18], sum2[1<<18]; 

int main()
{
    // some code 

}
```

It works great and doesn't bother about `a+b <= 34` , as you can see it works fine for `1<<18`.So what's happening under the hood.
Regards.

Comment: Because of [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977316/memory-allocation-for-global-and-local-variables has some useful comments on allocation issues

Comment: In the second attempt, did anything else change in the application besides moving the `sum1` and `sum2` declaration outside `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variables for your function go into the stack. Your stack size is not large enough to hold your arrays.

**Additional info:**

You can see your stack size with the following:

```
ulimit -s
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly explain why it works when the arrays are declared globally.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are usually allocated on the stack, and most systems have a relatively small limit on the size of a stack frame. Large arrays should be either global or allocated dynamically with `malloc()`.