# memory allocation for objects

Tags: c++, variables, heap-memory, stack-memory

When we instantiate a variable in c++ like `int x` within a function(i.e. x is a local variable), it is allocated on top of stack of the process. But if we do `int *x= new int`, the space is provided in heap.

So, my questions are:

1. What about objects of different classes (classes provided by c++ or user defined)? Where are their objects instantiated? For example: Let Employee is a class and we declare `Employee emp;`. Where is `emp` given space-> on stack or in heap?
2. If the declaration `int a[4]` is within a function, do all the four cells of `a` get space on stack?

Comment: I'd like to mention that `new`, if not overloaded, allocates space in the so-called free store, which isn't necessarily the heap, although in practice it is. If it **is** overloaded, `new` can do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It depends. If `Employee` has members, that are allocated only on the stack, then the whole object is. BUT, `Employee` may have pointer members and `Employee`'s constructor may allocate memory for them on the heap. Then some of the members are on the heap, some on the stack.
2. Yes.

Answer (score 11):

All local variables, no matter if from built-in types of from classes, or if they are arrays, are on the stack. All dynamic allocations are on the heap.

Of course, modifiers like `static` on a local variable will make the variable be put somewhere else, so it's preserved between function calls.

Also, to confuse you further, when you create a local pointer variable, and make it point to a dynamically allocated object, e.g.

```
Class* a = new Class;
```

The actual variable `a` is on the stack, but the memory it points to is on the heap.

---

Addendum: The C++ specification doesn't actually mention anything about stack or heap, only the behavior of different kind of variables.

Answer (score 7):

It's exactly the same as with normal types.

```
Class a; //stack. Usage: a.somethingInsideOfTheObject
Class *a = new Class(); //heap. Usage: a->somethingInsideOfTheObject
```

Note that if the class itself is allocating something on the heap, that part will always be on the heap, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        a = new int();
    }
private:
    int * a;
};

void foo()
{
    MyClass bar;
}
```

in this case the `bar` variable will be allocated on the stack, but the `a` inside of it will be allocated on the heap.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if `Class` makes use of `new` internally, that always uses the heap, even if `a` itself lives on the stack.

Comment: @NPE, true, but as long as you treat them as black boxes, you will hardly know it

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - true, bit it's still an important detail.

Comment: @meh, ok, I've added it to my answer

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: The reason I thought this detail was important is that if someone places a `std:vector<int>` on the stack, they shouldn't be expecting the contents of the vector to go on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

User defined classes (and types) are no different than built-in types.
So

```
Employee emp; // allocated in stack
Employee* emp = new Employee(); // allocated in heap
```

As for your second question, local arrays are allocated on stack

```
Employee emp[4]; // 4 instances on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the compiler knows about it at compile time (i.e. local variables), it's on the stack.
If the compiler doesn't know about it at compile time (i.e. dynamic allocation via `new`, `malloc` etc), it's on the heap.

This post has a detailed explanation: [global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap)