# How internally stack based object in c++ calls different methods of class ?

Tags: c++, function

I want to know how a stack based object calls methods of a class. What happens internally in memory and where does it save the address and name of the functions and how it maps it and call the exact method?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724390/memory-allocation-for-objects

Comment: This is implementation depended. Different compilers (or even compiler versions) may solve this problem using unsimilar approaches. See this article for an example: http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf

Comment: 'Stack based object' is mostly irrelevant. Non-virtual methods are called directly and resolved at link time. Virtual methods are called via a virtual function table or similar. The compiler may life that if it is confident the object is of the declared type, and 'stack based' is one such situation.

Answer (score -1):

> http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html.

please check this link for details of how function call was performed,Hope this will help you.