# Where are dynamic size arrays created on? (stack or heap)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, allocation

For example, I have an array with dynamic size based on user input:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int items[n];
```

Is this array allocated on stack? Or is it on heap like if I have written:

```
int n, *items;
cin >> n;
items = new int[n];
...
delete [] items;
```

**Edit:** I understand what the second code does. I'm asking whether the first code does the same thing like the second, but with less amount of lines.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169916/1141471

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first example isn't using a dynamic array at all - it's using a stack-allocated variable length array (which usually behind the scenes is equivalent to an `alloca` call, with the exception of the `sizeof` operator), which is a feature of C99, not C++.

Your second array, of course, is allocated on the heap via new.

Comment: Note that variable-length arrays are not supported in standard C++, so the first code snippet would be a syntax error in both C99 (no `iostream`s) and C++ (no VLAs). Nevertheless, some compilers support VLAs in C++ as an extension.

Comment: @Insilico correct, but many C++ compilers support C99 features as an extension (at least GCC, Clang, and maybe MSVC does).

Comment: @Insilico I will compile without warning. Tested with g++ without any build parameters.

Comment: It works because [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (which is what the first code snippet requires) are [supported by GCC as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). It's not supported in standard C++.

Comment: @Insilico Yes, I have read them all now. But why it compiles without any warning?

Comment: @Miro: A compiler is not required to issue warnings when you use extensions. The compiler writers of GCC chose not to have it issue warnings in this case (although you might if you compile with all warnings enabled).

Answer (score 3):

You use `new` for allocating memory, so your array is stored in heap

Comment: I'm asking what is behind the dynamic sized arrays, not what does the second code :)

Comment: Yes, the heap is what serves as the backing store for dynamically sized arrays in this case. What else would you like to know?

Comment: If you create an array without "new" or dynamic memory allocation functions, with a constant size, then it is stored in stack. If you allocate a memory for your array (and size may also be a non-const expression), then it's in heap.

Answer (score -1):

Your first block of code will fail to compile, you cannot allocate a dynamically sized array without the use of a memory allocation with either new or malloc/calloc/realloc.

In order to do what you want you will need to do what you have in the second block, which will be allocated on the heap always.

Dynamic = Heap. Non-dynamic = Stack.

Always remember to free your memory!

Comment: @Miro: It works because [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (which is what the first code snippet requires) are [supported by GCC as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). It's not supported in standard C++.

Comment: Please understand that the VLA shown in the first part of the question is a C99 extension, and is supported by most modern compilers.