# Will instantiating a class without the `new` keyword cause its internal variables to be created on the stack, or the heap?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

(In C++) Will instantiating a class without using the `new` keyword cause its internal variables to be created on the stack, if they are defined using the `new` keyword inside the class's constructor, or will they be created on the heap?

In other words, if we have a class or struct that contains a variable (an array for example) defined inside its constructor using the `new` keyword, will creating an instance of this class without using `new` cause the internal array to be created on the stack, or the heap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global memory management in C++ in stack or heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap)

Comment: @Suma I think this is surely not a duplicate of [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169858/2932052).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we have a class or struct that contains a variable (an array for
>   example) declared inside its constructor using the new keyword, will
>   creating an instance of this class without using new cause the
>   internal array to be created on the stack, or the heap?

yes, even if you create an object on stack (without `new` keyword) its internal data will be allocated on heap if new is used in class construcor (there might be exceptions when placement new is used to allocate data on stack - we'll see it later). Common example is allocating an array:

```
int main() {
    int* t = new int[100];  // pointer is on stack, data on the heap
    //...
}
```

and similarly:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){ 
        int* t = new int[100];
        std::cout<<"heap used\n";
        delete t;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    A a1;
    // ...
}
```

prints:

> heap used

and indeed, 100 `int`s have been allocated (and deleted) on the free store.

---

If you need to specify the memory location you can use **placement new**:

```
char buf[1024];
string* p = new (buf) string("on stack");  // pointer is on stack,
                                           // data on the stack
```

Comment: You should be more precise: the **pointer to the object is placed on the stack**, not the object itself.

Comment: what object? I am precise: pointer is on stack, data on the heap

Comment: This *even if you create an object on stack* is misleading, I think. I refer to the text, not the code snippet.

Comment: @WolfP. I might rewrite the answer, please just give me a hint what is misleading to you

Comment: Cut the clause *even if you create an object on stack its internal data will be allocated on heap if new is used* and paste it **before the second example**, that will do, basically.

Answer (score 3):

Operator new allocates memory in the heap unless you use the placement new operator where you can yourself point the memory used by the object.

Comment: I think the core message should be better separated from the detailed descriptions of the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code and assume no optimizations:

```
struct Foo {
    int* pointer_to_int;

    Foo() : pointer_to_int(new int) { }
    ~Foo() { delete pointer_to_int; }
}

void func() {
    Foo some_foo;
    Foo* some_other_foo = new Foo;
}
```

`some_foo` will be allocated on the stack. The stack will grow by at least `sizeof(Foo)` (which will be at least enough space to store a pointer to an integer (`sizeof(int*)`).

`some_other_foo` is stored on the heap because of the use of `new`. Again, at least `sizeof(Foo)` will be allocated, but this time from the heap.

The `int` that is created in Foo's constructor will be stored on the heap in both cases. This will increase the size of the heap by at least `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Possible typo: *The stack will grow*, you certainly meant the "heap (usage) grows".

Comment: @WolfP., whoops. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

- ordinary new (allocated on heap)
- placement new syntax (with memory already allocated)

...there is another option to use `new` that does not necessarily involve heap usage, that's the customized allocation by **overloading the operator new** (***and delete!***).

---

**Conclusion** (edit comment)

So, even if created using `new`, objects can reside

- on the **heap** (which is the **default** behaviour)
- in an existing piece of memory that it is placed on (**placement new** syntax)
- also anywhere else if the user wishes so (by **overloading new**)

The addresses returned by each of these new options can be stored everywhere in the address space of the calling process (stack, heap, or data segment).

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing.

Comment: @AlanStokes then this (third point above) was only a misunderstanding? Which would calm me down :) ...

Comment: @AlanStokes Now I removed the *bogus static syntax*. Pointers can of course be stored everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Anything created with a `new` is created on the heap.

Instantiating a class without using `new` will stack-allocate the class object. However its data members may or may not be stack allocated according to how they are instantiated.

By the way, `static` variables within functions are also heap allocated; this is how they are able to persist values between function calls.

Comment: `static` variables are *not* on the heap. They are statically allocated (given fixed addresses).

Comment: Initialized `static`variables go on the data segment and un-initialized ones go to .bss

Comment: @AlanStokes You are right,`static` variables are in data segment.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, of course you're correct (therefore a respectful +1) but the point I'm making is that they are not stack allocated - a common misconception.

Comment: Not everything created with new is created on the heap; placement new : `char buf[1024]; string* p = new (buf) string("hello"); cout << *p << endl;`

Comment: So data members which are allocated using `new` in the class' constructor will be heap-allocated even if the object is created on the stack?

Comment: @Mohammad The pointer members will be on the stack and the objects they point to on the heap.