# How memory is allocated for a variable declared outside vs inside main()

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have noticed when working with some large arrays (like doubles 1000 by 1000) that my program runs out of memory if I declare the array inside of main() but this never seems to happen if I declare the array outside main() even for larger arrays. Can someone explain what the distinction is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global memory management in C++ in stack or heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap)

Answer (score 10):

When a variable is declared inside a function (in your case, `main`), it's allocated on the stack, and if it's too large (e.g, a big array), you'll encounter [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables).

A variable defined outside all functions is allocated statically. Its lifetime lasts until the program terminates.

Comment: Does this mean that you can't encounter a stack overflow from allocation outside of all functions? I'm not sure if that's what you meant to imply or not.

Comment: @Human It does. Since the array is not on the stack you cannot get a stack overflow by putting it in global scope. If you declare too big arrays in global scope the system will eventually run out of memory and not be able to start the application. Same goes for heap allocations, impossible to produce a stack overflow but you can run out of heap memory.

Comment: @Human Stack overflow could be caused by various reasons, in this case, a very large stack variables, if a variable is defined outside of all functions, then it doesn't take stack space. But of course other types of stack overflow are still possible (very deep recursion, etc).

Answer (score 3):

It is implementation related issue. Theoretically defining a memory consuming variable should be possible in a function as same as global scope.

But in practice, the variables in global scope will be declared in data-segments of the target machine code and there is more available space to allocate. But, in the functions usually stack concept will be used which there is some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

On most systems, memory declared in a function will go on the stack, which is small and can overflow. However, memory declared outside `main()` will not be. The size (and existence) of the stack is implementation dependant - although I am not aware of any commonly used C++ systems where the stack does not exist.

---

Technically, memory declared inside a function has `automatic` storage duration, which means that it is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block, and is not valid after that code block finishes.

Memory declared outside of main has `static` storage duration, which means that it is allocated when the program starts, and is valid for the lifetime of the program.

See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for more on storage durations.

If you want to declare large amounts of memory inside a function, you can use the allocation functions `malloc` or `new`. [This link](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) clearly explains the difference between stack and heap (although it is about C rather than C++, it still applies to C++).

Comment: No, it won't be on the heap. It's allocated statically.

Comment: Ah, quite right. I've corrected the post and my memory :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's local to a function (`main` is just another function) it goes on stack. 1000x1000x8 = 8 million bytes. That is probably larger than the stack size. Different compilers may have different sizes, but I think the default is 1MB.

Global variables (they have static storage) are not allocated on the stack, nor the heap, but on a data segment whose size remains constants throughout the programs duration.

Notice that a process has more than just two memory areas, stack and heap. It also has a code/text segment, a data segment for initialized static variables in the program and another data segment called bss segment for uninitialized static variables. For more see [Anatomy of a Program in Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide whether the huge chunk of memory should be from heap (decide to have the array dynamically allocated) or from stack (have a local variable within some function, will be deallocated when not in scope), outside main puts data in global address space shared across all functions, gets allocated before main, and gets deallocated after main is done (on program exit).

Answer (score 0):

when your program will execute it will create one process which will be occupied fixed memory size in memory. this process contains four sections, data section, code section, heap and stack. out of these four sections, data and code section size is fixed, whereas size of stack(stores local variable, static data) and heap(stores data of dynamic memory allocation) will vary during the execution. Now if you are declaring your variable outside the main means in global area then it will be stored in data section of your process which has fixed size. so on the creation of very large array outside main will cause problem in data section. if you will store it in main, then its size can be managed by stack.

Answer (score -3):

the stack's size is about 2-3M,and heap's size is concerned with virtual memory.It can be very large. you can declare it like this `static int num[1000][1000];`